# Not able to use AppCompat v7 switchcompat widget

Tags: android, android-support-library, switchcompat

I want to use the Switchcompat in my application. I added the appcompat v7 support library into my project but when i am trying to use the switchcompat in my xml it is giving me following error :

The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

From the error I am guessing that my project is not able to refer the library project even though i have added the library project as shown :

[image]

My XML is as follows:
 
`<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>`

Kindly help what is the issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: try running your project and see if it's there?

Comment: You may want to try cleaning & rebuilding the support library first, followed by the same steps for your main project.

Comment: @MH.: Tried cleaning and running the project , Getting the following runtime  error : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat"

Comment: Are u able to preview switch widget in xml layout?

Comment: @Harry No. In XML it is giving me error as i have mentioned in the question

Comment: In your project structure can u find android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat under 'Android Private Libraries'?

Comment: @Harry : No its not there. Under android dependencies i can fine the appcompat v7 library.

Comment: Have u updated support lib from sdk manager?

Comment: @Harry : Yes I am using Rev. 22

Answer (score 0):

Try adding android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to build path in library.
You should be getting similar view if you are doing all right!

[image: Sreenshot]

Comment: If you got SwitchCompat class listed than you are up!

Comment: I tried that still it is not showing ..In the project explorer for my project it is not showing the Android private libraries folder.

Comment: When you create a new project(eclipse) Android private libraries by default appears man! and let me guess you are using Theme.AppCompat style in project right?

Comment: I am using  Theme.AppCompat style in project , I created new project in which i am able to use the switch but the private libraries folder is not present in the old project while in the new project evrything is there as you mentioned. I am not able to understand what i have missed.

Comment: I am using other library projects also in my application due to which i get build error as follows : Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies. Is it because of this the private libraries are not getting generate?

Comment: Jar mismatch mostly happens when u have different versions of appcomatV4 library included in library project and your project. Be aware of that.